# How to use async/await syntax with forEach loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've looked at several questions on using async/await with a forEach loop but nothing seems to cover my user case... How can I get the code below to work? Right now I'm getting the following error:

> await is a reserved word

Here's the code:

```
export const fetchUserBookmarks = ( bookmarksIDs ) => async ( dispatch, getState, api ) => {

    dispatch({
        type: 'IS_FETCHING_BOOKMARKS'
    });

    try {

        bookmarks = [];

        bookmarksIDs.forEach( bookmarkID => {
            const bookmark = await api.get( selectedPostByIdEP + bookmarkID ); 
            bookmarks.push( bookmark ); 
        }); 

        dispatch({
            type: 'HAS_FETCHED_BOOKMARKS', 
            payload: bookmarks
        });

    } catch( error ) {

        dispatch({
            type: 'FAILED_FETCHING_BOOKMARKS', 
            payload: error
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: add `async` to forEach loop, `bookmarksIDs.forEach(async bookmarkID => {...})`

Comment: sure, that would work, but not as expected, for example, `dispatch` will be called  before anything is pushed to bookmarks regardless of what you do inside forEach - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First,** To use `await` you should declare the function as `async`. You have done so with the outer function but not with the inner function.

The change will look something like this:

```
bookmarksIDs.forEach(async bookmarkID => {
```

**Second,** what you probably want is to run those api calls in parallel.

You can replace `forEach` with a `map` call and await all the resulting promises together.

To do that your code should look something like this:

```
const bookmarks = await Promise.all(
  bookmarksIDs.map(bookmarkID => 
    api.get( selectedPostByIdEP + bookmarkID )
  )
);
```

--

It seems that if `bookmarks` is not declared anywhere else it causes a problem. using `const` or `let` should solve that problem.

Comment: How does the first step relate to the second step?

Comment: The first point is to show what's missing in your code. The second point is to show how to modify the code to run in parallel, if that is what you intended to do.

Comment: But `async` isn’t missing. Putting it there wouldn’t work at all.

Comment: You can't use `await api.get` in the inner without it. But I agree, that is why I prefer the solution in the second part of my answer.

Comment: @TalZ OP here. I've just tried your code (second part) but it doesn't seem to work for me. More precisely, the requests are being made and are successful (I can see that in the inspector's Network tab), but in fact any code that follows the `Promise.all` snippet doesn't execute. Even just a `console.log` prints nothing to the console...

Comment: Nope, the requests are being made and are successful (I can see that in the inspector's Network tab).

Comment: prints nothing or doesn't reach the `console.log`?

Comment: Doesn't reach it. But I think I've just fixed it: adding a `const` before `bookmarks` made it work! I will update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` isn’t a loop; it’s a function that you pass a function to. There’s no way to get a promise out of it. If you want to perform `api.get`s one by one, you can use a for loop:

```
for (const bookmarkID of bookmarksIDs) {
    const bookmark = await api.get(selectedPostByIdEP + bookmarkID); 
    bookmarks.push(bookmark); 
}
```

and if you want to do them in parallel, you can create several promises and use `Promise.all` to collect their results:

```
const bookmarks = await Promise.all(
    bookmarksIDs.map(
        bookmarkID => api.get(selectedPostByIdEP + bookmarkID)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> forEach loop is not compatible with promise and async functions. Use
> `for.. of` loop instead. It would work fine.

```
async(data)=>{
    const ids = ["xyz","abc"]
    for (const id of ids){
    let data = await Collection.findById(id)
    console.log(data)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this instead

```
try {

    bookmarks = await Promise.all(bookmarksIDs.map( bookmarkID => api.get( selectedPostByIdEP + bookmarkID )); 

    dispatch({
        type: 'HAS_FETCHED_BOOKMARKS', 
        payload: bookmarks
    });

}
```